# Spacefilling Turtle Curve with Tikz

Tags: grid, latex, tikz, hilbert-curve

I'm trying to draw some space-filling curves with tikz and the Lindenmayer system. 
My goal was this curve:

[image: Goal]

So I tried it out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[lindenmayersystems]

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Turtle}{
 \rule{L -> +FFFF-FR}   %rule 1
 \rule{R -> -FFFF+FL}   %rule 2
}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \shadedraw [bottom color=white, top color=white, draw=black]
 [l-system={Turtle, axiom=L, order=6, step=0.25cm, angle=90}]
 lindenmayer system;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

For "order=6" this results in:
[Curve with Order 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDD13.jpg)

This should be the third picture in the first row of the first picture. 
But when i tried it out, I ran into 2 Problems: \

1. I don't want that last little line at the bottom right. \
2. Rule 1 and Rule 2 are not filling up a space, but rather building a curve which keeps on getting longer and longer for bigger orders.

So my question is, is there a rule for which I get my space-filling curve which are dependend on the order? Or can this be done without the depency of the order?

As an aditional task I also tried to get a grid in the background, so that I get cells size is equal to a step, but I did not get the scale right, when I wanted to make in dependent on the order. I tried it with

```
...
lindenmayer system;
\draw[step=0.25cm, gray, very thin] (0,0) grid (1,1);
...
```

But just as before, this does not scale and we can clearly see how the curve does not fill up this space (grid):

[image: Curve with grid]

Can anybody help me or give me advise?